# How does getItem() work in Android in ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to pass the position of an image that is clicked in one fragment to a Pager FragmentActivity so that it's displayed in a screen slide. I pass the position in the intent to the Pager, but the getItem() always starts the screen slide from the first image in my album instead of the image that I clicked.

In my `ImageListFragment`:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        final int imageResId = mImageResIds[position];

        viewHolder.setData(imageResId);
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = FooPager.newIntent(getActivity(), position);
                startActivity (intent);
               // mListener.OnGalleryImageSelected(imageResId);
            }
        });
    }
```

And then in my `Pager` FragmentActivity:

```
public static final String EXTRA_IMAGE_ID = "meow";
        public static int id = 0;
        private ViewPager mViewPager;
        private Integer images [] = {
        R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d,R.drawable.e,
        R.drawable.f, R.drawable.g, R.drawable.h,R.drawable.i,R.drawable.j,
        R.drawable.k, R.drawable.l, R.drawable.m,R.drawable.n,R.drawable.o,
        R.drawable.p, R.drawable.q, R.drawable.r
};

public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, int id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext,FooPager.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_ID,id);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_pager);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById (R.id.activity_image_pager_view_pager);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager ();
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            int id = images[position];
            return ImageDetailFragment.newInstance(id);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return images.length;
        }
    });
```

`position` in getItem() always starts at 0, and therefore always selects the first image in my `./drawable` directory. How do I make it so that the position in getItem() is consistent with the position of the image that I am clicking in my `ImageListFragment`? At this point, `getItem()` is unaware of the position coming in from the intent, but I am not sure how to fix this without making `getItem()` display the same image over and over (in screen slide mode).

Here is more of the code:

http://pastebin.com/QgPfEisu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are starting a new activity on each click in the following code:

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = FooPager.newIntent(getActivity(), position);
    startActivity (intent);
    // mListener.OnGalleryImageSelected(imageResId);
    }
});
```

Since the `Activity` is starting over, everything resets. See [this example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) for a better and more standard way to handle what you are trying to do.

---

*To pass data from `Fragment` to `Activity`:* You build your `Intent` in `Pager` and pass it to the `FooPager Activity` as follows:

*Pager*

```
public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, int id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext,FooPager.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_IMAGE_ID,id);
    return intent;
}
```

*ImageListFragment*

```
Intent intent = FooPager.newIntent(getActivity(), position);
startActivity (intent);
```

To pick up `EXTRA_IMAGE_ID` in `FooPager`, add the following code to `FooPager`'s `onCreate`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
id = extras.getInt(EXTRA_IMAGE_ID);
```

There should also be some additional checking for null `extras` and missing `EXTRA_IMAGE_ID`, but this is how to get data from `ImageListFragment` to the `Activity`.

Comment: So how to I go from my ImageListFragment to the `FragmentStatePagerSupport` that is described in the link? (If creating a new intent with each click triggers a new activity).